# preload script not loaded in packaged app

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-packager

I've made a small Electron app which needs to load a preload js file.

When I start the app with `electron .`, it finds the file, but when the app is packaged, it doesn't.

The call is made here:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
   width: 800,
   height: 600,
   webPreferences: {
     nodeIntegration: false, 
     nativeWindowOpen: true,
     webSecurity: false,
     preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')  
  }
})
```

My simplified package.json:

```
"name": "app",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "main.js",
"scripts": {
  "start": "electron .",
  "build": "electron-packager . --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --overwrite"
 }
"devDependencies": {
  "electron": "^1.8.4",
  "electron-packager": "^12.0.1",
}
```

My project structure:

- node_modules

- main.js

- preload.js

- package.json

I've checked the result of the `path.join` and in both cases, the path is correct, and the file is there.

Comment: Could you try replacing `path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')` with `'./preload.js'`

Comment: Already tried this ! Tried many paths and seems not be the problem... ^^'

Comment: First, do you get a specific error when running the packaged app? Second, does your app have a webview? If so, rather than passing the preload script to the BrowserWindow constructor, try adding an attribute to the `webview` tag: `preload="preload.js"` (assuming the file is adjacent to the page you're loading in your window)

Answer (score 8):

For peoples using Electron Forge webpack typescript boilerplate :

1. Add the `preload` key in `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "plugins": [
        [
          "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
          {
            "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
            "renderer": {
              "config": "./webpack.renderer.config.js",
              "entryPoints": [
                {
                  "html": "./src/index.html",
                  "js": "./src/renderer.tsx",
                  "name": "main_window",
                  "preload": {
                    "js": "./src/preload.ts"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Preload script can be a typescript file.

2. Add `MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY` constant as value for `preload`:

```
// Tell typescript about this magic constant
declare const MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY: any;

// [...]

  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 1000,
    width: 1500,
    webPreferences: {
      preload:  MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
    }
  });
```

3. In `preload.ts` write :

```
import {
  contextBridge,
  ipcRenderer
} from 'electron';

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
  'electron',
  {
    doThing: () => ipcRenderer.send('do-a-thing')
  }
)
```

4. Add `index.d.ts` file, write :

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    electron: {
      doThing(): void;
    }
  }
}
```

5. Start your app, in your dev console you can type `electron` and view it is defined.
6. BONUS: getting the typing right for the contextBridge exposed API:

Why a separated fie ? Not sure if needed, but I prefer not having to import an interface from a file that contain main process code (like preload.ts) in renderer process.

```
// exposed-main-api.model.ts

export interface ExposedMainAPI {
  doThat(data: string): Promise<number>;
}
```

```
// index.d.ts

declare global {
  interface Window {
    electron: ExposedMainAPI
  }
}
```

```
// preload.ts
import {
  contextBridge,
  ipcRenderer
} from 'electron';

const exposedAPI: ExposedAPI = {
  // You are free to omit parameters typing and return type if you feel so.
  // TS know the function type thanks to exposedAPI typing. 
  doThat: (data) => ipcRenderer.invoke('do-that-and-return-promise', data)
};
// note: this assume you have a `ipcMain.handle('do-thing-and-return-promise', ...)` 
// somewhere that return a number.

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', exposedAPI);
```

Credits:

- @deadcoder0904 that gave us the solution in an [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49875179/preload-script-not-loaded-in-packaged-app#comment107743399_60150348) to a previous answer, here is the github issue he link : https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge/issues/1590
- `index.d.ts` typing and small example usage of `contextBridge`: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9920#issuecomment-743803249

See also:

- Explanations about security and also an example of using IPC: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9920#issuecomment-575839738

Answer (score 6):

Preload script needs to be specified as an absolute path. Thus it will differ from the time you're running it in development versus running it packaged as an asar file.

```
const getSourceDirectory = () => isDev()
    ? path.join(process.cwd(), 'build', 'src') // or wherever your local build is compiled
    : path.join(process.resourcesPath, 'app', 'src'); // asar location

const preload = path.resolve(getSourceDirectory(), 'preload.js');
```

Comment: it worked for me in development because i knew the path but doesn’t work in production as there’s no `preload.js` there as i use `electron-forge` which uses `webpack` which bundles all files into a single file. how do i do it? i have written more about my use case [here on a Github issue](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge/issues/1590)