# electron preload not working when building app (windows)

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-forge

While the preload script loads ok when developing `yarn start`

It does not on builds `yarn make`

```
Unable to load preload script:
```

```
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1800,
    height: 1600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      sandbox: false,
      preload: path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'preload.js')
    },
  })
```

Is there any evident reason for that?

Answer (score 2):

Several questions and issues about this one, such as

- https://gist.github.com/bbudd/2a246a718b7757584950b4ed98109115
- [preload script not loaded in packaged app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49875179/preload-script-not-loaded-in-packaged-app)
- https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge/issues/1590
- [Can't use static files in electron forge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839621/cant-use-static-files-in-electron-forge)
- https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack/issues/321
- [Why does preload.js return "ERROR: module not found"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58653223/why-does-preload-js-return-error-module-not-found)

The answer is this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/67176486/826815, adapted for js, also described in the docs https://www.electronforge.io/config/plugins/webpack#project-setup

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
  }
});
```

```
              "entryPoints": [
                {
                  "html": "./src/index.html",
                  "js": "./src/renderer.js",
                  "name": "main_window",
                  "preload": {
                    "js": "./src/preload.js"
                  }
                }
```

Being preload.js in the `/scr/` folder, and checking that afterwards it is present in the `/out/` folder

Comment: setting any `entry` in webpack make preload stop to work. Any idea What could possibily be the reason?